# Telegram-cli doesnt accept all messages

Tags: python-3.x, telegram

I'm using `telegram-cli` and pytg to group all my messages. For some channels I can't receive the messages using this configuration. I'm using a Linux script to run `telegram-cli`:

`bin/telegram-cli -P 4458 -W --json -E accept_secret_chat` &

Do you know what's wrong?